# Accessing Webpages Using Proxies In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, socks, proxies

I am new in python. I am doing web scraping. I use googlesearch module to get links in python. But after so many requests google blocks my ip. So I used tor and then by using socks I do the same task but the same thing happened again. Now I come to the solution that I should use proxies. But when I made a request using proxies it throws an exception.
Below is the code which I use. I run chrome browser by setting proxies manually and it works very well but why it is throwing exception when I access using python.

```
import requests
    proxies = {'http': 'socks5://user:pass@host:port',
               'https': 'socks5://user:pass@host:port'}
    resp = requests.get('http://https://www.google.com', proxies=proxies )
```

Comment: *"But after so many requests google blocks my ip."* - Don't ask questions here how to circumvent Terms of Service. If your IP gets blocked then you're violating Google's rules. Nobody here will give you any tips about that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your URL. the URL should be `https://www.google.com/` but your code has the wrong URL. other than that if you still get an error try adding user-agents with the request.

```
import requests

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5://user:pass@host:port',
    'https': 'socks5://user:pass@host:port'
}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
}
resp = requests.get('https://www.google.com', proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
```